# Raspi python script keeps crashing

Tags: python, while-loop, crash

I own a 3d printer which is connectet to a raspberry. To controll (like shut on and off via relais) the printer remotely, I made a small python script.

One possibility to controll it is to use the Telegram Bot (telepot) which seems to work properly.
The other method to shut the printer on and off is a hardware switch. For secutity reasons, I want the printer to shut off only if the switch is pressed for 3 seconds.

The problem is, the script crashes sometimes (most at after a long uptime).
I assume that it's my while loop at the end, but I don't really understand why it only crashes after a variable amount of time and how to improve that.
That's the code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import subprocess
import os
import datetime
import telepot
import urllib
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

chat_id_auth = XXXXXXXXXXX


# Warnungen ausschalten
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# Pin Nummern verwenden
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
# Pin 11 als Input
GPIO.setup(29, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(11, 0) #on

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print 'Got command: %s' % command    
    if chat_id == chat_id_auth:    
        if command == '/status':
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'online')
        elif command == '/picture':
            bashCommand = 'wget --output-document snapshot.jpg http://127.0.0.1:8080/?action=snapshot'
            subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True)
            print ('downloaded photo')
            bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, open('snapshot.jpg','rb'), caption='Printer Status')
            print ('sent photo')
            bashCommand = 'rm snapshot.jpg'
            subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True)
            print ('removed photo')
        elif command == '/ip':
            bashCommand = 'ifconfig eth0 | grep \'inet addr:\' | cut -d: -f2 | awk \'{ print $1}\''
            output = subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True)
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, output)
            print(output)
        elif command == '/on':
            #bashCommand = 'echo \'0\' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value'
            #output = subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True)
            GPIO.output(11, 0) #on
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Drucker wird eingeschaltet..')
            #print(output)
        elif command == '/off':
            #bashCommand = 'echo \'1\' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value'
            #output = subprocess.check_output(bashCommand, shell=True)
            GPIO.output(11, 1) #off
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Drucker wird ausgeschaltet..')
            #print(output)    
    else:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'You are not authorized.')



bot = telepot.Bot('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
bot.message_loop(handle)
print 'I am listening ...'


global n
n=0
while True:
    if GPIO.input(29):
        if  GPIO.input(11) == 0:
            if n >= 300: #Taster 3s halten zum Ausschalten
                GPIO.output(11, 1) #off
                n=0
                time.sleep(2)
        elif GPIO.input(11) == 1:
            GPIO.output(11, 0) #on
            n=0
            time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        n+=1
    else:
        n=0
    print n 

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a clear reason for a crash but the while loop at the end seems to be very busy waiting when nothing is done (no button pressed).  From what I understand it then prints 0 and loops without any delay, so it will print zeros as fast as it can and keeping the Raspi busy as much as possible.  Maybe that load is the indirect reason for any crash you experience (but that is just wild guessing).

Anyway, I propose to improve on that massively busy waiting.  Even if it does not address the crashes, it would improve your code.  To achieve this, simply add a `time.sleep(0.1)` in the `else:` branch to loop at most ten times per second (and not as fast as the CPU can).

In any case you should debug the situation.  Find out why there is a crash.

- Log your output into some file. (`./script.py >& script.log`)
- `try`/`except` your exceptions and print debugging stuff in case you catch some.
- Whoever starts it should monitor its exit code and log it.

  - Unix signals received result in an exit code of 128 + the signal number.
  - Type `kill -l` on the command line to see a list of all signals and their numbers.